# Why PHPExcel_IOFactory can read ? almost ? all files via the HTML Reader

Tags: php, validation, phpexcel

I have an input type file in my `form`, and I've give all type of most used extension to test if I can reach the [Exception](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php#L287) :

```
throw new PHPExcel_Reader_Exception('Unable to identify a reader for this file');
```

All my tests are not conclusive enought since all of common used extension use the HTML Reader, the others [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php#L222) use the correct expected reader with my code :

```
public function initExtract(SomeDeps $deps, array $document)
    {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $fileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($document['tmp_name']);
        $reader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
        $this->excel = $reader->load($document['tmp_name']);

        var_dump($reader, $this->excel);
    }
```

I was wondering then why `PNG, JPG, GIF, PDF or TXT` used the [HTML Reader](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/HTML.php) and are readable ?
And why there is no test for this reader with [this method](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/HTML.php) to determine if exist a HTML DOM in the provided document ?
Just a "<" is not enought IMO

Did I missed something ? Is the Exception above really used ? For what extension ?

This is for determine precisely what extension I have to check in `formValidation` because PhPExcel is maybe too much permissive.

Comment: I'm cofused as to why you expect  an excel reader to handle a gif.

Comment: Exactly my point here @Dagon, an input file can basically accept all of type of file, i saw an exception is throwable in the PHPExcel code, i decide to test this thrown, i just admit now this Exception is not thrown ever, that's all (see Mark Baker's comments where he says that this Exception is never thrown)

Answer (score 1):

Genuine OfficeOpenXML files (xlsx) should use the `Excel2007` Reader, genuine BIFF-format files (xls) should use the `Excel5` Reader.... but just because a file has an extension of `xls` or `xlsx`, doesn't mean that it is a genuine BIFF or OfficeOpenXML format file.

If PHPExcel identifies a file (irregardless of extension) as HTML, and uses the HTML Reader, open that file in a text editor and see what it really is. HTML will be easily readable as markup; genuine BIFF-format xls or OfficeOpenXML-format xlsx files are binaries, so will be pretty obviously different.

As for why we have a [simplistic check](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/HTML.php#L131), we don't expect people to throw any type of file imaginable at PHPExcel without having some idea of whether it is likely to be a spreadsheet file or not; but perhaps if this i insufficient IYO, then you could modify the checking method to provide a more comprehensive validity check, and submit that as a PR

Comment: I think I understand what you mean (post your edit), but it's not completely answer to my question, is the Exception thrown for a specific extension ? I could try to make a PR I think it will be interesting to work on that

Comment: I found that, if file is not readable with HTML reader, then CSV file will return true in all case, so the exception is never thrown right ?

Comment: Basically yes, CSV is the catchall, that's almost impossible too validate (different delimiters, quotes, etc make it too difficult to put a validation check in for CSV) so anything that isn't explicitly detected as a specific spreadsheet filetype falls into the CSV category, and the exception is never reached

Comment: Ok now I understand, IYO, do you think then this Exception deserve to exist anymore ? Is the CSV catch up a good idea and the exception a bad one ? Inverse ?